# String compare returns false eventhough they are the same

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SerialTrial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public class ThreadExample
    {
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

        public static void ThreadJob(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            string dBConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SerialTrial\SerialTrial\bin\Debug\CompanyList.sqlite;";
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString);
            //open connection to database
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from AllEmployee", sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader reader;
                reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

                int count = 0;
                //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                List<string> mystring = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count++;
                    string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(Variables.buffering, reader.GetString(0))));

                    Console.WriteLine(Text);

                    mystring.Add(Text);
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                    {
                        mystring.Add("1");
                        //string myText = new TextRange(mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.ContentStart, mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

                        //replace two or more consecutive spaces with a single space, and
                        //replace  two or more consecutive newlines with a single newline.
                        //var str = Regex.Replace(myText, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                        //Int64 id = reader.GetInt64(0);
                        string fname = reader.GetString(1);
                        string sname = reader.GetString(2);
                        DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;

                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(saveNow.ToString())))));
                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.AppendText(": ")));
                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.AppendText(fname)));
                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.AppendText(" ")));
                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.AppendText(sname)));
                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.AppendText(" granted access to gate 1")));                      
                        string text = "s";
                        mainWindow.WriteSerial(text);
                        //Console.WriteLine(Text);

                        //Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}, Name = {1}, Surname = {2}, Age = {3}", id, fname, sname, age);
                        //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", reader.GetInt64(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3));

                    }
                }
sqliteCon.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
        //string received_data;
        //Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select Port");
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            string[] ports = null;
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();


            // Display each port name to the console. 
            int c = ports.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                if (!combobox1.Items.Contains(ports[i - 1]))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(ports[i - 1]);
                }

            }
        }
        string dBConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SerialTrial\SerialTrial\bin\Debug\CompanyList.sqlite;";

        static int count = 0;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            string[] ports = null;
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();


            // Display each port name to the console. 
            int c = ports.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                if (!combobox1.Items.Contains(ports[i - 1]))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(ports[i - 1]);
                }

            }

        }
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {   
            int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
            Console.WriteLine(bytes);
            if (bytes == 14)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
                serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
                System.String ID = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
                //System.String ID = new String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer));
                Console.WriteLine(ID);
                foreach (var item in ID)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }
                /*
                Console.WriteLine();
                string s2 = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
                string tempAry = s2.Replace("-", "");
                Console.WriteLine(tempAry);

                Variables.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
                 */
                Variables.buffering = ID;
                Console.WriteLine();
                //Console.WriteLine(Variables.buffering);
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }

        }
```

I am sending 0x02,0x37,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x32,0x42,0x34,0x30,0x38,0x45,0x39,0x35,0x03 in a serial port equivalent to 70002B408E95. This ID Code is also 70002B408E95 in my database. Why is it that my compare.Equals return false eventhough both string is true?

Variables.buffering is in my class to make buffering global.

```
class Variables
    {
        public static System.String buffering;

    }
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Where in your code is the error occuring? You have provided a lot of code... Have you tried debugging what does the inspector tell you?

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of code to support your relatively simple question. Have you tried a very small console application that shows the same problem?

Comment: At the point when you call `Object.Equals`, what **exactly** are the contents of `Variables.buffering` and `reader.GetString(0)` ? what are there `.ToCharArray()` outputs? What do they hold? Also: You should just use `==` here: `Variables.buffering == reader.GetString(0)`

Comment: You convert 0x02 in the beginning and 0x03 in the end to string as well. While you'd want to skip them if you convert to string. Try `.GetString(buffer, 1, 12)`.

Comment: Variables.buffering  is in a class to make it global. There is no error but the output is not what I expect since the string that I receive from the serial is the same in the database. How is my code returning false? This code is: string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(Variables.buffering, reader.GetString(0))));

Comment: the content of Variables.buffering is 70002B408E95 and the reader.GetSting(0) is still 70002B408E95.

Comment: @user3464920 what is the value of `Variables.buffering.Length`?

Comment: Thanks Ulugbek Umirov, your suggestion works. Can you post your answer so we can close this. System.String ID = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer,1,12);

----but can I ask why 1 and 12? What does it represents?

Comment: @user3464920 I added the answer. 1 - start reading from byte at 1st position (0x37 in your case), 12 - take 12 bytes.

Comment: oh. sorry I know what 1 and 12 represent. HEHE. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive `0x02,0x37,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x32,0x42,0x34,0x30,0x38,0x45,0x39,0x35,0x03` as your data. I guess **0x02** and **0x03** are kind of **start** and **stop** bytes. What is between them is your ASCII string. Thus you need to ignore these **start** and **stop** bytes, by replacing your code:

```
System.String ID = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
```

with

```
System.String ID = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 1, 12); // start reading from byte at 1st position and take 12 of them
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.Equals compare addresses

```
    Object.Equals(Variables.buffering, reader.GetString(0))
```

Try with String.Equals to compare strings

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments below, this not only does not work, but is also wrong, so dismiss my answer

Comment: I try to change to this one: string Text = (String.Format("{0}", String.Equals(Variables.buffering, reader.GetString(0))));
---- but it still returns false

Comment: If you use Object.Equals with strings it will call string.Equals

Comment: so how will I check for the similarity of the two strings? One is from serial port and the other one is from my sqlite database

Comment: How about Variables.buffering == reader.GetString(0) as suggested above ?

Comment: object.Equals does *not* compare addresses.  It does whatever the overridden `Equals` method does of the first instance provided.  The *default* implementation for reference types is to compare references, but that's only done *when no other implementation is provided*.  String overrides `Equals` to provide value semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we compare value type variable or reference type variable . If you compare int,string kind of variable with int ,string then you should go for value type like 1=1 or "a"="b" , but when you compare with object ,you should go with reference type like 1.equal(1) or a.equal(b)